# Cordova emulator not working

Tags: android, windows, cordova, batch-file

I tried to run the generated apk by using the command-
cordova emulate android,

However I'm getting the following error

`ANDROID_HOME=C:\StreamSoftwares\FrontEndSoftwares\adt-bundle-windows-x8620131030(Updated)\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
'C:\StreamSoftwares\FrontEndSoftwares\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

My android home is set to the following path:

C:\Softwares\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030(Updated)\sdk

Can someone please explain the problem. Can it be because of parenthesis or hyphens in the path? I tried executing

`set "ANDROID_HOME=C:\Softwares\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030(Updated)\sdk"`

But it didn't work

Comment: That's the problem. I'm working in my office and my company doesn't authorize me to rename it.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! Using caret for escaping didn't work but subst Z: did the trick! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parentheses in the path are clearly a problem for some tool in the toolchain.

If you cannot rename the path because of lack of privileges (or lack of insight from the administrators :)), you can add this to your startup script:

```
subst Z: C:\StreamSoftwares\FrontEndSoftwares\adt-bundle-windows-x8620131030(Updated)\sdk
```

Then you can use `ANDROID_HOME` as `Z:`

(if `Z` drive letter is already taken, choose another)